# Spring boot 2.2.0 - Multipart File upload failing with error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to do file upload API in my spring boot application.Below is my controller method

```
    public CertificateRequest uploadfileAndParse(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request){
        CertificateRequest certificateRequest = new CertificateRequest();
        if(!file.isEmpty()){
            certificateRequest.setCity("UN");
        }

        return certificateRequest;
    }
```

I  have configured multipart properties in the application.properties file like below

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB
```

In request Header, I have set the Content-Type property as multipart/form-data

But I am getting the following error while uploading file

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been providedat org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2802) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
```

Not sure what else I am missing.
while debugging I also found that

context.getAllowCasualMultipartParsing() is coming as false .Looks like multipart configuration are not set in the tomcat context .I am using embedded tomcat .

Comment: Could you provide the payload of your request? It seems that everything is good except the data provided in the payload

Comment: browser shows the formData like as ` ------WebKitFormBoundaryNolkqM1CoYnFYDz5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain


------WebKitFormBoundaryNolkqM1CoYnFYDz5--`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed the issue . In my springApplication class `MultipartAutoConfiguration` was excluded

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MultipartAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Fixed it by removing "MultipartAutoConfiguration.class" from the exclusion list

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following configuration based on version

**Spring Boot 1.3.x and earlier**

```
  multipart.maxFileSize
   multipart.maxRequestSize
```

**Spring Boot 1.4.x and 1.5.x**

```
spring.http.multipart.maxFileSize
spring.http.multipart.maxRequestSize
```

**Spring Boot 2.x**

```
spring.servlet.multipart.maxFileSize
spring.servlet.multipart.maxRequestSize
```

Currently, you are using 2.x
 then you can change your config to

```
spring.servlet.multipart.maxFileSize
spring.servlet.multipart.maxRequestSize
```

Comment: have you tried with  @RequestMapping(consumes = "multipart/form-data")

Comment: yes added  @RequestMapping(value="uploadfile",consumes = "multipart/form-data") as annotation for the API method .. still getting the same error

Comment: getAllowCasualMultipartParsing this property is returns false always which throwing an exception  from Request.java  available under connector folder of embedded tomcat jar .

Comment: you are running war file inside tomcat? or simple spring boot application ?

Comment: Its a simple spring boot application. so far i havent configured any thing other than application.properties